# Why [@(!var) class] return' __NSCFNumber rather' than' __NSCFBoolean'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, llvm

When I passing a dictionary `@{@"MUTE":@(flag)}` to `+[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]`, it return a JSON like `{ "MUTE" : true }`, which is what I expect.

But when I change my dictionary into `@{@"MUTE":@(!flag)}`, it produce a JSON like this `{ "MUTE" : 0 }`, which is not acceptable by our server.

So I write some test code to find out what's happend here:

```
BOOL var = YES;
NSLog(@"%@", [@(var) class]);       // print __NSCFBoolean
NSLog(@"%@", [@(!var) class]);      // print __NSCFNumber
NSLog(@"%@", [@((BOOL)!var) class]);// print __NSCFBoolean
```

**It seems that logical NOT expression produce a non-BOOL type value.**

But the clang tells me a different story after rewriting code above in C++:

```
BOOL var = ((bool)1);

NSLog((NSString *)&__NSConstantStringImpl__var_folders_vg_0k7tkth9043fl0g9sf5l9l3w0000gn_T_main_8479d3_mi_0, ((Class (*)(id, SEL))(void *)objc_msgSend)((id)((NSNumber *(*)(Class, SEL, BOOL))(void *)objc_msgSend)(objc_getClass("NSNumber"), sel_registerName("numberWithBool:"), (BOOL)(var)), sel_registerName("class")));
NSLog((NSString *)&__NSConstantStringImpl__var_folders_vg_0k7tkth9043fl0g9sf5l9l3w0000gn_T_main_8479d3_mi_1, ((Class (*)(id, SEL))(void *)objc_msgSend)((id)((NSNumber *(*)(Class, SEL, BOOL))(void *)objc_msgSend)(objc_getClass("NSNumber"), sel_registerName("numberWithBool:"), (BOOL)(!var)), sel_registerName("class")));
NSLog((NSString *)&__NSConstantStringImpl__var_folders_vg_0k7tkth9043fl0g9sf5l9l3w0000gn_T_main_8479d3_mi_2, ((Class (*)(id, SEL))(void *)objc_msgSend)((id)((NSNumber *(*)(Class, SEL, BOOL))(void *)objc_msgSend)(objc_getClass("NSNumber"), sel_registerName("numberWithBool:"), ((BOOL)!var)), sel_registerName("class")));
```

Anyone knows what's wrong in `@(!var)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the C part of Objective-C. The C logical operators, such as `&&`, `||` and `!` all compare their operands to being (un)equal to 0 and return an `int` value of 0 or 1. This stems from C not originally having any built-in boolean type.

So in your expression `@(!var)` the `!var` has type `int` and an `__NSCFNumber` object is created.

HTH